# What is alphablend and what functions are used for it?

Tags: winapi, windows-ce

What is alphablend and what functions are used for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AlphaBlend function displays bitmaps that have transparent or semitransparent pixels.
And the function used for alphablend is :

```
 BOOL AlphaBlend(HDC hdcDest,
                 int nXOriginDest,
                 int nYOriginDest,
                 int nWidthDest,
                 int nHeightDest,
                 HDC hdcSrc,  
                 int nXOriginSrc,
                 int nYOriginSrc,
                 int nWidthSrc,
                 int nHeightSrc,
                 BLENDFUNCTION blendFunction
                );
```

Please refer the following link->  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452850.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The AlphaBlend function displays bitmaps that have transparent or semitransparent pixels.